# making .so file using code::blocks

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, shared-libraries

How can i make a `.so` file using `Code::Blocks` ? I installed `Code::Blocks` for linux. I have been using it to make a `.dll` in windows.

*A Shot from project selection :*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `Shared Library`. A static library is a library that is included in the executable file of the binary it liks with. Although they are simpler to use, they increase program size and the difficulty of updates. When you link a shared library, all that is included in the binary is a reference to the name of the library, and the library file is usually found in one of the lib folders: /usr/lib, /lib, /usr/local/lib, /opt/lib, etc.

It's worth mentioning that shared libraries require one of three things during runtime:

- A compilation command that includes this option: `-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/dir/with/shared/lib/file`
- Or, you have to put the `.so` file in one of the `lib`s (listed above)
- Or, add the directory with the library file to the environment variable, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 1):

You want to make a shared library.

Comment: how is it different from `static library` ?

Comment: a static library is meant for linking the program statically, meaning including the library inside the executable.

Comment: @grassPro When a static library is linked with an application, the code from the library is put into the resulting executable. A shared library is loaded by the OS when the program starts, and is shared between multiple programs. Just like a DLL.

Comment: @grassPro: A static library is a library that is included in the executable file of the binary it liks with. Although they are simpler to use, they increase program size and the difficulty of updates. When you link a shared library, all that is included in the binary is a reference to the name of the library, and the library file is usually found in one of the `lib` folders: `/usr/lib`, `/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, `/opt/lib`, etc.